# COALESCE function in NOT statement not working

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT COALESCE(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(expires_at), 0) FROM main_db.`device` WHERE main_db.`device`.`device_id` ='6' and NOT main_db.device.device_type = 'mac';
```

The query returns nothing, but COALESCE doesn't kick in to return 0.  I believe this has something to do with the NOT statement.

I did this test:

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULL, 0) FROM main_db.`device` WHERE main_db.`device`.`device_id` ='6'
```

and it returns 0.

Comment: Are you getting any result with ``SELECT * FROM main_db.`device` WHERE main_db.`device`.`device_id` ='6' and NOT main_db.device.device_type = 'mac';`` ?

Comment: I'm guessing that you are getting 0 rows, but expecting to have 1 row with `0` in the only column? `COALESCE` will only apply if you have rows to return, it doesn't create a row if none exists.

Comment: Input sample with expected output are welcome

Comment: The query that "works fine" has a different where clause!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put this in a `subquery`.

```
select COALESCE((SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(expires_at) expires_at
    FROM main_db.`device` 
    WHERE main_db.`device`.`device_id` ='6' and NOT main_db.device.device_type = 'mac'), 0);
```

Comment: This is because `COALESCE` operates on a row. But as your query does not have any results, there is nothing to operate on.

Comment: @FerdyPruis, try this https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=hCPJDw6E0z

Comment: @Cid, totally different, my answer is `select coalesce(subquery, 0)`

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ aah yes, true